# Traverse in nested arrays in JSON data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion, nested

I have the data like this:

```
    {
        {
            "text" : "parent1",
            "nodes" :[
                {
                    "text": "child1",
                    "nodes": [
                        {
                            "text": "grandchild1",
                            "nodes":[
                                {
                                    "text": "hello",
                                    "nodes": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "text": "hello",
                            "nodes":[]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "text" : "parent2",
            "nodes" :[
                {
                    "text": "child2",
                    "nodes": [
                        {
                            "text": "grandchild2",
                            "nodes": [
                                {
                                    "text": "grandgrandchild1",
                                    "nodes": [
                                        {
                                            "text": "hello",
                                            "nodes": []
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]

                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

What I want is, creating a path array that contains the path of the elements whose "text" value is "hello". For example, according to this data:

```
var paths: any[][] = [
    ["parent1","child1","grandchild1","hello"],
    ["parent1","child1","hello"],
    ["parent2","child2","grandchild2","grandgrandchild1","hello"]
];
```

I want this "paths" array. Please notice, if the element's text value is "hello", then this element's "nodes" length is 0. I think I'm making a mistake in recursion.

Comment: *I think I'm making a mistake in recursion* Please share your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

- **Traverse** the object using recursion,
- **Assign** paths along the way
- and finally keep **record those paths** when the current text matches the text.

**Demo**

```js
var obj = [{
    "text": "parent1",
    "nodes": [{
      "text": "child1",
      "nodes": [{
          "text": "grandchild1",
          "nodes": [{
            "text": "hello",
            "nodes": []
          }]
        },
        {
          "text": "hello",
          "nodes": []
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    "text": "parent2",
    "nodes": [{
      "text": "child2",
      "nodes": [{
        "text": "grandchild2",
        "nodes": [{
          "text": "grandgrandchild1",
          "nodes": [{
            "text": "hello",
            "nodes": []
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }
];

var helloPaths = [];
var valueToSearch = "hello";
function traverseAndCreatePath( obj, parent, valueToSearch )
{
    if ( Array.isArray( obj ) )
    {
        obj.forEach( function(item){          
           traverseAndCreatePath( item, parent, valueToSearch );
        });
    }
    else
    {
        if ( parent )
        {
            obj.path = parent.path.slice();
            obj.path.push( obj.text );
        }
        else
        {
            obj.path = [ obj.text ];
        }
        if ( obj.text == valueToSearch )
        {
           helloPaths.push( obj.path.slice() );
        }
        if ( obj.nodes && obj.nodes.length )
        {
            obj.nodes.forEach( function(item){          
               traverseAndCreatePath( item, obj, valueToSearch );
            });
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
traverseAndCreatePath( obj, null, valueToSearch );
console.log( helloPaths );
```

Comment: I have one more question. According to this solution, what should I do for creating array without path's text value but with index of this node ? So the array that I want should looks like this:

[0,1,1,0,2],[0,1,0] ...

Answer (score 0):

This is a Depth First Traversal

```js
var counter = 0;
var finalArray = []

function test(arr, node) {
  arr.push(node.text);
  if (node.hasOwnProperty("nodes") && Array.isArray(node.nodes) && node.nodes.length != 0) {

    node.nodes.forEach(function(nodeChild) {
      test(arr, nodeChild);

    })

  } else {
    finalArray[counter] = arr.slice();
    counter++;


  }
  arr = arr.slice(0, -1);

}
var b =[ { "text" : "parent1", "nodes" :[ { "text": "child1", "nodes": [ { "text": "grandchild1", "nodes":[ { "text": "hello", "nodes": [] } ] }, { "text": "hello", "nodes":[] } ] } ] }, { "text" : "parent2", "nodes" :[ { "text": "child2", "nodes": [ { "text": "grandchild2", "nodes": [ { "text": "grandgrandchild1", "nodes": [ { "text": "hello", "nodes": [] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ]  
b.forEach(function(nodeVal) {
  test([], nodeVal)

})
console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function should recieve:

1. A list of nodes of any length

And return:

2. A list of paths of any length

For the base of this behavior, we'll use `reduce`. It loops over the list once, and can keep adding to the result when needed.

```
const helloPathsFromNodes = (nodes = [], paths = []) =>
  nodes.reduce(
    /* TODO */ ,
    paths
  )
```

For each node, you check whether it's the end of an *individual* path to determine if you need to recurse. To keep track of the current path, we'll need to pass along an additional parameter (`path`) and add to it along the way:

```
if (node.text === "hello") return [...path, "hello"]
else return goDeeper([...path, node.text])
```

Putting this together, you get:

```js
const helloPathsFromNodes = (nodes = [], paths = [], path = []) =>
  nodes.reduce(
    (acc, { text, nodes }) =>
      text === "hello" ?
        [...acc, [...path, text]] :
        helloPathsFromNodes(nodes, acc, [...path, text]),
    paths
  );

console.log(helloPathsFromNodes(getData()));


// Example Data
function getData() { return [ { "text" : "parent1", "nodes" :[ { "text": "child1", "nodes": [ { "text": "grandchild1", "nodes":[ { "text": "hello", "nodes": [] } ] }, { "text": "hello", "nodes":[] } ] } ] }, { "text" : "parent2", "nodes" :[ { "text": "child2", "nodes": [ { "text": "grandchild2", "nodes": [ { "text": "grandgrandchild1", "nodes": [ { "text": "hello", "nodes": [] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ]  };
```

Comment: I have one more question. According to this solution, what should I do for creating array without path's text value but with index of this node ? So the array that I want should looks like this:

[0,1,1,0,2],[0,1,0] ...

Comment: You add a third argument to the reduce method: (acc, { text, nodes }, **i**). Instead of adding text to the path, you add i: [...path, i]

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thank you so much.